Qemu virtual machine not responding through VPN
I have a machine with openvpn server and some virtual machines on it. I used to have them in VirtualBox (network: bridge) but I'm moving to QEMU.
Everything except the machine that I've moved to QEMU works OK. The newly moved machine, however, cannot reply to me when I'm accessing from VPN (connection is reset by peer). It works fine when accessed from LAN. All other machines (virtualbox) can still reply to me normally over VPN.
I'm assuming I'm missing a route that would tell the virtual machine how to access 10.8.0.0/24?
Here are the details:
QEMU/VPN/Virtualbox HOST IP: 192.168.99.20
QEMU guest static IP: 192.168.99.19
OPENVPN net: 10.8.0.0/24


root@R3:~# nmcli connection show
NAME    UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
br0     c66d9827-b2f3-4ab3-bfdd-6d1e5ffe383e  bridge    br0    
10G-BR  08aa8e2b-df95-408d-aeb2-a7f2b04ebf23  ethernet  enp1s0 
lo      e886dbf1-d7fd-4af3-a796-3e03a905db70  loopback  lo     
tun0    52629a83-8049-4f8e-992b-2a720abbf857  tun       tun0   
vnet2   cc718301-2dc7-4691-afb4-dcc4f6e6e317  tun       vnet2 


root@R3:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:92:26:d1:21:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:fe:ce:ea:d6:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ea:6e:5b:0a:b2:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.99.20/24 brd 192.168.99.255 scope global noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a00:ee2:1205:fc00:6e3:89aa:7e1d:f181/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 889sec preferred_lft 889sec
    inet6 2a00:ee2:1205:fc00:210f:23c8:b78a:3007/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 889sec preferred_lft 889sec
    inet6 fe80::cfb8:a019:63af:9832/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:72:34:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe72:3428/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ae8f:b2f9:8f98:a495/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



root@R3:~# route 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    425    0        0 br0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.99.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     425    0        0 br0


And firewall rules for accessing LAN and NET from VPN (changed that from enp1s0 to br0 and it now the net and LAN work over VPN):
root@R3:~# iptables -A FORWARD -o br0 -i tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
root@R3:~# iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
root@R3:~# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE


Any ideas?
Thanks!
